# python append pandas to postgresql. dataframe has differing columns

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to load several panda dataframes to a postgresql database. they differ slightly in their number of columns and this gives out an error. Do you know a workaround?

See my code:

```
import geopandas as gp
from sqlalchemy import *
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry, WKTElement
import psycopg2

for tablename in fileslist:
    gdf1=gp.read_file("name.geojson")
    gdf1['geom'] = gdf1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: WKTElement(x.wkt, srid=25833))
    gdf1.drop('geometry', 1, inplace=True)
    gdf1.to_sql('{}'.format(tablename), engine, if_exists='append', index=False,dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type=geometrytype, srid=25833)})
```

the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "example" of relation "tablename" does not exist
```

I am processing a geojson and I load it with geopandas instead of pandas and I have to do some geo-operations before I can further process it. I dont think that this has any impact on the process but I included it just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround for this:

First use an SQL query in your python code to get the columns that already exist in your table. (I'm writing the query for PostGreSql, change it as per your database)

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM public."%s" LIMIT 0' % tablename)
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
```

where 'cur' is your cursor and 'tablename' is the name of your table.

Then get the names of your columns in your current dataframe.

```
colsnow = list(gdf1.columns)
```

If your dataframe has new columns, add these columns to your table and then append your dataframe to your table.

```
setdiff = list(set(colsnow).difference(set(colnames)))
if len(setdiff)!=0:
    for i in range(len(setdiff)):
        cur.execute('ALTER TABLE public."%s" ADD COLUMN "%s" text' % (tablename, str(setdiff[i])))
con.commit()
```

'con' here is your psycopg2 connection object.

So your code should look somewhat like this.

```
import geopandas as gp
from sqlalchemy import *
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry, WKTElement
import psycopg2

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM public."%s" LIMIT 0' % tablename)
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

for tablename in fileslist:
    gdf1=gp.read_file("name.geojson")
    gdf1['geom'] = gdf1['geometry'].apply(lambda x: WKTElement(x.wkt, srid=25833))
    gdf1.drop('geometry', 1, inplace=True)

    colsnow = list(gdf1.columns)

    setdiff = list(set(colsnow).difference(set(colnames)))
        if len(setdiff)!=0:
            for i in range(len(setdiff)):
                cur.execute('ALTER TABLE public."%s" ADD COLUMN "%s" text' % (tablename, str(setdiff[i])))
    con.commit()

    gdf1.to_sql('{}'.format(tablename), engine, if_exists='append', index=False,dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type=geometrytype, srid=25833)})
```

Comment: Thanks! Since also in the database are sometimes more columns than are in the database, I added an additional section where these are added to the pandas dataframe if not present